# Java jdbc connector doesn't insert row but i dont get error message

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am having a strange problem with JDBC and java, I have this code:

```
Connection connection;
Statement st;
String sentence;

public ConnectorMYSQL() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ehu", "root", "root");
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        st = connection.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void crearProyecto(String pNombreProyecto, String Creador, String Buscado) {

    java.sql.Timestamp date = new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());

    String cadena = "INSERT INTO proyecto (nombreproyecto, fechacreacion, creador, buscado,eliminado) VALUES ('"
            + pNombreProyecto + "','" + date + "','" + Creador + "','" + Buscado + "','0');";
    System.out.println(cadena);
    try {
        //st.executeUpdate(cadena);
        st.execute(cadena);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error con: " + cadena);
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

When I run crearProyecto() I didn't get any error message but it didn't add the line to the table, but if I enter the same query with phpmyadmin it works.
Even more, the id is Auto_increment and it count the times I did via java.

Comment: Did you try to commit? Since you set auto commit to false

Comment: @VeselinDavidov Very nice catch.  And also, use prepared statements (though I believe the insert should actually work as is right now).

Comment: Concatenating values like that into a query string is unsafe (look up SQL injection). Please learn how to use a prepared statement with parameters.

Comment: yeah prepared statements would be better. There are other stuff to improve too - like closing the connection in finally block instead of keeping it as class property and stuff like that. Java variables shouldn't be Uppercased etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change something in DB, it will not be persistent. It can be shown only on your session. If you want it to be persistent, then you should commit. When a session is committed, then all changes become persistent which means all sessions can access these data.

In your case, you close auto_commit, so inserted rows are shown only in this session. So you can see inserted rows if you select from java code. But you cannot see these inserted rows from phpmyadmin because it connects to DB with different session.

**Solution:** 
Change setAutoCommit to true.

```
  connection.setAutoCommit(true);
```

**Edit:**
The default auto_commit value is true as Mark Rotteveel mentioned in the comment. So it's better not to use setAutoCommit(true). You can delete this line.

Comment: The default is auto-commit true, the OP is explicitly disabling it, so it would be better to suggest to remove that line or to explicitly use commit.

Answer (score 0):

A problem could be the `'0'` in ''. Removing the quotes helped me some times to solve my inserts. It's better to use a `PreparedStatement`, because in this case the JDBC driver will take care about the correct formatting of the Data.

```
public void crearProyecto(String pNombreProyecto, String Creador, String Buscado) {

    java.sql.Timestamp date = new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    try {
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `proyecto` "
            + "(`nombreproyecto`, `fechacreacion`, `creador`, `buscado`, `eliminado`)"
            + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, pNombreProyecto);
            preparedStatement.setDate(2, date);
            preparedStatement.setString(3, Creador);
            preparedStatement.setString(4, Buscado);
            preparedStatement.setInt(5, 0); 
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error con: " + cadena);
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```